# Primary Key MVC

Tags: sql, database, model-view-controller

How can i reset primary key.
I deleted all the rows in my database in MVC. 
Now i make a new profile and i get primary key ID as value 80.
I want "1,2,3,4".

Comment: Probably you want `DBCC CHECKIDENT (table_name, RESEED, 1)` to reset IDENTITY column

Comment: Do `truncate table <table>`.  This resets the primary key.

Comment: next time, use TRUNCATE table :)

Comment: What **database system** are you talking about? SQL is just the query language - not a database product ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use on database:

DBCC CHECKIDENT(TABLE, RESEED,1)

Right click over table, and select New Query and run this command here.

Comment: visual studio ,mvc project. where i do it?

Comment: run this SQL query on enterprise manager, replace TABLE with you table name. Of course, if you are using SQL server.

Comment: Alex, what engine are you using?

Comment: i am using visual studio 2013. i've created a database with entity framework code first with migrations

Comment: Alex, look for "Server explorer" Option, option "Data connections". You must be have at least one connection, the name may be different, but usually is "DefaultConnection". Right click over connection, and select New Query. you can run this command here. when you create a Entity framework model, you need store data on a Database.

Comment: By default, Entity framework create a LocalDB, that is a SQL Server Database. You can access to this database through Enterprise Manager (you can download this from microsoft), look into your web.config, on tag <connectionStrings>. Please Refer SQL enterprise manager for SQL Express install and download. This step is not always necessary to manage database, but I prefer access using this tool. Hope this helps.